# Windows 7 and XAMPP: pear is not recognized as an internal or external

Tags: php, windows, netbeans

Very first time working with PhpDocumentor and I am stuck. I have tried many different way to fix it but nothing works, so seeking help here.

I am using `Netbeans` editor in Windows 7 with XAPP and trying to install `PhpDocumentor` but when I am trying to install using `pear install --alldeps PhpDocumentor` in `cmd` it is giving me message

```
'pear' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Here are some details about the setup:

Netberans installed in `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 7.4`
XAMPP installed in 'D:\xampp\'

I checked `D:\xampp\php\' and found`pear.bat`file there as well as there is a directory called`pear`as well in`php`folder and path is`D:\xampp\php\pear`

I have crossed check the `pear` and found folder `PhpDocumnetor` already there.

I have also added Environment Variable for `PATH` as below

```
C:\Users\meuser\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\xampp\php
```

Now in command line I am doing as below

```
C:\Users\meuser>pear install --alldeps PhpDoumentor
```

resulting `pear is not recognized...` error.

I am confused, since `PhpDoumentor` directory already there in `D:\xampp\php\pear\PhpDoumentor` do I really need to install it?

If no than why I am not able to see `phpDoc` tab in `Netbeans > Tools > Options > PHP`

How to fix this issue so I can generate documentation for my Netbeans project?

Comment: try to run those call pear something to D:\xampp\php\pear something?

Comment: I have tried as you said but not working and giving the same error. When I tried with `D:/xampp/php` it is giving some error with `pp_imagick.dll` not found and I have place the file in `php/ext` but still giving the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh `php.exe - Entry Point Not Found` Error message: `The procedure entry point php_checkuid_ex could not be located in the dynamic link library php5ts.dss.`

Comment: Okay now seems working but when I am trying to install it is giving me an error `Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'D:\xampp\php\php_imagick.dll' - The specified procedure could not be found.` in Unknown on line 0 pear/PhpDocumentor is already installed and is the same as the released version 1.4.4 `install failed`

Comment: I think you need to slowly see the error message and go back to those line to fix, mostly due to the wrong reference if you install them abnormally